# Экспорт canvas изображения в PDF

Tags: pdf, canvas, php, html5, javascript

pdf canvas php html5 javascript

Comment: лучше плодите вопросы, формат хешкода такой что это можно и нужно делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берете полученный png отправляете на сервер с php, там используете любой генератор pdf для php([например](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31438/)) для вставки картинки в pdf, сохраняете pdf на диск и даете как ответ ссылку на pdf. Изменение mime-type на другой не конвертирует png в pdf =)

PS Я думаю вам стоит заморочится, судя по всему опыта у вас не много, а он вам нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант это легко можно сделать и на стороне клиента силами JS.

Для этого :

- из канваса создаем картинку (или даже массив картинок чтобы потом
  сделать многостраничный PDF)
- рендерим картинки в PDF файл c помощью [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)
- сохраняем его на сервер или отправляем пользователю

```js
//Эта часть кода просто инициализирует канвас для наглядности
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  // Create gradient
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 50, 5, 90, 60, 100);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "white");

  // Fill with gradient
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

});


function Convert() {
  //По нажатию на кнопку получаем канвас
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  // И создаем из него картиику в base64
  var quality = 1; // качество от 0 до 1, заодно и сжать можно
  var myImage = {
    data: canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality),
    height: canvas.height,
    width: canvas.width
  };
  // теперь из картинки делаем PDF
  createPDF(myImage);
}

//image - должен иметь свойста height,width и data - хранит картинку в base64
function createPDF(image) {
  let w = ConvertPxToMM(image.width);
  let h = ConvertPxToMM(image.height);
  var orientation = w > h ? 'l' : 'p';

  //Создаем документ PDF размером с нашу картинку
  var docPDF = new jsPDF(orientation, 'mm', [w, h]);
  //рисуем картинку на всю страницу
  docPDF.addImage(image.data, 'JPEG', 0, 0);

  //Сохраням полученный файл
  //Возможные значения : dataurl, datauristring, bloburl, blob, arraybuffer, ('save', filename)
  docPDF.output('save', 'test.pdf');
}

function ConvertPxToMM(pixels) {
  return Math.floor(pixels * 0.264583);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="Convert();">Сделай мне PDF из этой картинки</button>
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```